# Error al enviar datos a mysql con ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

Estoy intentando enviar datos desde un formulario con JS a PHP mediante Ajax pero no consigo que se envien.

Este es el codigo de una hoja aparte de JS

```js
function objetoAjax() {
  var xmlhttp = false;
  try {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (E) {
      xmlhttp = false;
    }
  }
  if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  return xmlhttp;
}

function Registrar() {
  ID = document.frmMascotas.ID.value;
  Nombre = document.frmMascotas.Nombre.value;
  Fecha = document.frmMascotas.Fecha.value;
  Raza = document.frmMascotas.Raza.value;
  Especie = document.frmMascotas.Especie.value;
  //    alert("Datos "+ID+" "+Nombre+" "+Fecha+" "+Raza+" "+Especie);
  ajax = objetoAjax();
  ajax.open("POST", "Registrar.php", true);
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
      alert('Los datos se guardaron con exito');
      window.location.reload(true);

    }
  }
  ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  ajax.send("ID=" + ID + "Nombre=" + Nombre + "Fecha=" + Fecha + "Raza=" + Raza + "Especie="
    Especie);
}

Aquí está el codigo HTML
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CRUD Mascotas</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div align="center" class="starter-template">
      <h1 align="center"><b>CRUD CON AJAX</b></h1>
      <button type="button" id="btnmodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>Nuevo
       </button>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Lista de mascotas</div>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID Mascota</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Fecha De Nacimiento</th>
            <th>Raza</th>
            <th>Especie</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php 

                    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","crud-ajax");
                    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM MASCOTA"); 
               while($filas=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
               { ?>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <?php echo $filas['idmascota']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $filas['nombre']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $filas['fechanacimiento']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $filas['raza']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $filas['especie']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Seleccione</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                          <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a>Eliminar</a></li>
                  <li><a>Actualizar</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <?php    
               }
               ?>



        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Registrar Mascota</h4>
          </div>
          <form role="form" action="" name="frmMascotas" onsubmit="Registrar(); return false">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>ID Mascota</label>
                <input name="ID" class="form-control" required>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nombre</label>
                <input name="Nombre" class="form-control" required>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Fecha De Nacimiento</label>
                <input name="Fecha" type="date" class="form-control" required>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Raza</label>
                <input name="Raza" class="form-control" required>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Especie</label>
                <input name="Especie" class="form-control" required>
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Registrar
                </button>

            </div>
          </form>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>x</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#btnmodal').click(function() {
        $('#modal').modal('show');
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Aqui está el codigo PHP
*Hoja Registrar.php*

```
<?php
require('Conexion.php');
$IDmascotas = $_POST['ID'];
$Nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
$Fecha = $_POST['Fecha'];
$Raza = $_POST['Raza'];
$Especie = $_POST['Especie'];

$Query = "INSERT INTO mascota (idmascota,nombre,fechanacimiento,raza,especie) 
VALUES ('$IDmascotas','$Nombre','$Fecha','$Raza','$Especie')";
$Reg = mysqli_query($conexion,$Query);

mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

*Hoja Conexion.php*

```
<? php
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","crud-ajax");

?>
```

Comment: revisa tu cadena en ajax.send(), ya que los campos deberian estar separados por & y en tu caso no los tienes asi.

Comment: Los datos deben ser enviados así: `ajax.send("ID="+ID + "&Nombre="+Nombre + "&Fecha="+Fecha + "&Raza="+Raza + "&Especie="+Especie);` (nótese que te faltaba un `+`). También, puedes serializar el formulario (particularmente útil en formularios grandes), o puedes valerte de la API `FormData`, más moderna, pero no soportada por todos los navegadores. Para fines de depuración, convendría que pusieras los datos en una variable: `var data = "ID="+ID+"&Nombre="+Nombre+"&Fecha="+Fecha+"&Raza="+Raza+"&Especie="+Especie` entonces para enviarla: `ajax.send(data);` y para depurar: `console.log(data);`

Comment: Veo que estás utilizando jquery, por qué mejor no utilizas la función ajax de el mismo?